# Unable to establish a simple websockets connection with my node server

Tags: node.js, websocket, node-websockets

I'm trying to get a very barebones websocket server to work, but for some reason my browser is unable to establish a connection. When I load my HTML page I get the following error

```
error:index.html:9 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/?chatId=15432' failed:
```

Here's what my **server** looks like:

```
const http = require("http");
const WebSocketServer = require("websocket").server;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {});
const websocket = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server,
  autoAcceptConnections: false,
});

const chats = new Map();

websocket.on("request", (request) => {
  let connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  console.log(connection);
  console.log(new Date() + " Connection accepted.");
  let chatId = request.resourceURL.query.chatId;

  if (!chats.has(chatId)) {
    chats.set(chatId, []);
  }

  chats.get(chatId).push(connection);

  connection.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("Received Message: " + message.utf8Data);
    let chatConnections = chats.get(chatId);
    chatConnections.forEach((chatConnection) => {
      if (chatConnection !== connection) {
        chatConnection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        console.log(connection);
      }
    });
  });
  connection.on("close", (reasonCode, description) => {
    console.log(
      new Date() + " Peer " + connection.remoteAddress + " disconnected."
    );
    let chatConnections = chats.get(chatId);
    chatConnections.splice(chatConnections.indexOf(connection), 1);
    if (chatConnections.length === 0) {
      chats.delete(chatId);
    }
  });
});
server.listen(8080, "localhost", () => {
  console.log("listening on port 8080");
});
```

And here's my **client** looks like (i.e. the html file that I'm opening in my browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      let webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080?chatId=15432", null);
      webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
        webSocket.send("Hey guys, here's my first message");
        console.log("Connection Opened Client");
      };

      webSocket.onclose = function () {
        console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting a connection to occur and to receive a message from the client, but that's not happening for some reason. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `onRequest` seems to be the core issue. You should use the `websocket.on('connection' ...` method:

Something like this:

```
// USER CONNECTED (onload events)
wss.on("connection", async function connection(client, request) {
  console.log("user connected", Date.now());
  client.send(JSON.stringify({ ready: true }));

  ...
  
});
```

Consider [this barebones Websockets chat implementation](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/simple-chat-react17-websockets-express-q3x118) I recently wrote which you can fork and use. It's using React 17 but should work with React 18. Once the WSS is ready, it lets the client know and the client and start communicating - then see a ping-pong communication. The Score and Session naming for the components are arbitrary.

**./package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "node": "^19.6.0",
    "ws": "^8.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run dev\" \"npm run dev_client\"",
    "dev": "node index.js",
    "dev_client": "cd ./client && npm run start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Wesley LeMahieu",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**./index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import http from "http";

const heartbeat = (ws) => {
  ws.isAlive = true;
};

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 4443 });

wss.on("close", function close() {
  console.log("closed");
});

wss.on("open", function connection(client) {
  console.log('sent "open" to client');
  client.send("open");
});

// USER CONNECTED (onload events)
wss.on("connection", async function connection(client, request) {
  console.log("user connected", Date.now());
  client.send(JSON.stringify({ ready: true }));

  // CLIENT ALIVE-CHECK
  client.isAlive = true;
  client.on("pong", () => heartbeat(client));

  // message all clients in the ui
  client.on("message", async function message(d, isBinary) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      const data = JSON.parse(d.toString());
      console.log("client message", { data });
      client.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          score: Math.random(),
          session: Math.random(),
          ...data,
        })
      );
    }
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.port || 4444, () => {
  console.log(`*~~% wesley's server %~~*`);
});
```

**./client/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-chat-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A barebones Websockets chat client",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

**./client/src/index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { socket, SocketContext } from "./context";

import App from "./App";

render(
  <StrictMode>
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      <App />
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**./client/src/context.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4443");
export const SocketContext = React.createContext();
```

**./client/src/App.js**

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SocketContext } from "./context";
import Score from "./Score";
import Session from "./Session";

export default function App() {
  const websocket = useContext(SocketContext);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [sentMessages, setSentMessages] = useState([]);

  // since websocket is the same instance shared between components,
  // once websocket.onmessage is set here, it's set. subsequent
  // components will not create their own listener because the listener
  // is already set once.

  console.log("USE EFFECT APP.JS");
  useEffect(() => {
    websocket.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      const packet = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log("app.js packet", packet);
      if (packet.ready) setIsReady(packet.ready);
    });
  }, [websocket]);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ message }));
    setMessage("");
    setSentMessages((msgs) => [...msgs, { message }]);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          margin: "1rem",
          columnGap: 5,
        }}
      >
        <Score />
        <Session />
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", columnGap: 5, margin: "1rem" }}>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <input id="message" value={message} onChange={onChange} />
          <button type="submit" disabled={!isReady}>
            Send
          </button>
        </form>
        <div>
          {!isReady ? (
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Initializing WSS...</span>
          ) : (
            <span style={{ color: "green" }}>WSS Ready!</span>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
        {sentMessages.map((msg, key) => (
          <div key={`row-key${key}`}>{msg.message}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**./client/src/Score.js**

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SocketContext } from "./context";

const Score = () => {
  const websocket = useContext(SocketContext);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  console.log("USE EFFECT SCORE.JS");
  useEffect(() => {
    websocket.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      const packet = JSON.parse(e.data);
      setScore(packet.score);
    });
  }, [websocket]);

  return <div>Score: {score}</div>;
};

export default Score;
```

**./client/src/Session.js**

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SocketContext } from "./context";

const Session = () => {
  const websocket = useContext(SocketContext);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(0);

  console.log("USE EFFECT SESSION.JS");
  useEffect(() => {
    websocket.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      const packet = JSON.parse(e.data);
      setSession(packet.session);
    });
  }, [websocket]);

  return <div>Session: {session}</div>;
};

export default Session;
```

**./public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```